# Using ClearCase MultiSite VOBs

Tags: clearcase

I have an environment with two replicated VOB servers. Not all the VOBs are replicated to each other: in some VOBs we have users that do check-ins from both sites (each site into different streams). Besides, there are some local VOBs on each site.

1. How do I know if a replicated VOB has check-ins on a specific
   replica? Alternatively: how do I know if a replicated VOB has
   check-ins on both replicas?
2. Do replicated VOBs must be on the same ClearCase registry?
3. How do I know the local VOBs? `cleartool lsvob -host local-hostname` ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can checkout for checkouts with a [lscheckout](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lscheckout.htm) command, but you cannot easily find new version on a replica: the easiest way is to wait for the synchronization and see if any new version have been created since the last sync (with a [`cleartool find created_since`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8909280/6309)).
2. Considering ClearCase is accessing one registry server at a time, it is best to have all vobs appropriately referenced (tagged and registered) in one registry (to [avoid messages like "Unable to find replica in registry for VOB with object ID"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21247263))
3. You can follow "[Determining which replica is associated with a VOB on the local host](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21236992)"

   ```
   cleartool describe -l vob:\avob
   ```

Look for a line "`replica`": if there is none (or if it is without value), it is a local vob (not replicated)

Comment: 1) cleartool lsco or cleartool find could take very long time... Is there any command to know if a VOB has been ever touched in a given site?

Comment: @user1762109 maybe with [`cleartool lshistory replica:replica-name[@vob-selector]`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm): it does display history in reverse chronological order, and you don't have to display the *full** history, only the most recent events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multitool lsepoch -invob \VOB to determine, if anything has be changed by the replicas.
Each action (checkin, checkout, mklabel...) will represented by one epoch counter.